# Googlevis, R shiny : not in a new window

Tags: r, shiny, googlevis

I have a problem. I am trying to use package Googlevis with R shiny and I have some problems.

```
 library (googleVis)
    library(shiny)
    library(shinythemes)

df=data.frame(annee=c("2000","2005","2010","2014","2015","2016","2017"), val= c(30.0,27.0,29.7,28.6,28.8,29.4,26.))
graph2 <- {gvisLineChart(df)}

shinyApp(
  ui = navbarPage(
    theme = shinytheme("yeti"),"Pageweb",
    tabPanel("Page1",
             sidebarPanel(
               tags$em("TEXTE TEXTE TEXTE TEXTE TEXTE TEXTE TEXTE TEXTE TEXTE TEXTE TEXTE")
               ),
             mainPanel(
               tabsetPanel(
                 tabPanel("Onglet1", plotOutput("graph1"), "Texte de présentation", plot(graph2)),
                 tabPanel("Onglet2"),
                 tabPanel("Onglet3")
               )
             )
               )),
  server = function(input, output) {

    output$graph1 <- renderPlot({
      y = c(30.0,27.0,29.7,28.6,28.8,29.4,26.)
      barplot(y,names.arg=c("2000","2005","2010","2014","2015","2016","2017"),main="Titre graph1",
              xlab="Années", ylab="Pourcentage (en %)", col="#2345AA", border="#515353",space=0.3,
              ylim=c(0,35), density=c(30))
    })  
  }
  )
```

The graph created with Googlevis opens in a new window but i want to implemant it in the R shiny page. I tried htmloutput function without results.

If someone has an idea to put the graph made by Googlevis in the page made by R shiny

```
df=data.frame(annee=c("2000","2005","2010","2014","2015","2016","2017"), val= c(30.0,27.0,29.7,28.6,28.8,29.4,26.))
    graph2 <- {gvisLineChart(df)}
```

Also, I am forced to declare those 2 lines at the begining. If not, the variable is not found.

Comment: What do you mean by R shiny page and htmloutput function? Have you tried knitting it as a Markdown? Markdown can support interactive documents; perhaps that may coerce the googlevis to be in the same Window.

Comment: For me, R shiny page is the page generated with the 3 tabs "Onglet1", "Onglet2", "Onglet3". It's my first time with R shiny and i have never used R markdown. So i am trying to find a possible easy solution to capture the representation made by googlevis to include it in my previous page

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32756687/combine-r-shiny-and-googlevis-motion-chart  In this page, it seems to be possible but when i am trying this, it didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

With googleVis plots, you need the same logic as with any other plot. In the same way you render your `graph1` with `plotOutput` in the UI and `renderPlot` in the server, for the googleVis graph2 is the same, using `htmlOutput` in the UI and `renderGvis` in the server:

```
library (googleVis)
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

shinyApp(
  ui = navbarPage(
    theme = shinytheme("yeti"),"Pageweb",
    tabPanel("Page1",
             sidebarPanel(
               tags$em("TEXTE TEXTE TEXTE TEXTE TEXTE TEXTE TEXTE TEXTE TEXTE TEXTE TEXTE")
             ),
             mainPanel(
               tabsetPanel(
                 tabPanel("Onglet1", plotOutput("graph1"),
                          "Texte de présentation", htmlOutput('graph2')),
                 tabPanel("Onglet2"),
                 tabPanel("Onglet3")
               )
             )
    )),
  server = function(input, output) {

    output$graph1 <- renderPlot({
      y = c(30.0,27.0,29.7,28.6,28.8,29.4,26.)
      barplot(y,names.arg=c("2000","2005","2010","2014","2015","2016","2017"),main="Titre graph1",
              xlab="Années", ylab="Pourcentage (en %)", col="#2345AA", border="#515353",space=0.3,
              ylim=c(0,35), density=c(30))
    })
    output$graph2 <- renderGvis({
      df=data.frame(annee=c("2000","2005","2010","2014","2015","2016","2017"), val= c(30.0,27.0,29.7,28.6,28.8,29.4,26.))
      gvisLineChart(df)
    })
  }
)
```

In shiny, most widgets (`leaflet`, `plotly`, `googleVis`...) provide output and render functions to use in the UI and server, respectively. In this case the [`renderGvis`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/googleVis/versions/0.6.2/topics/renderGvis) function.

The data and googleVis chart creation can be put on the `renderGvis` function, similar at what you did in the `renderPlot` call.